# echo: write error: Operation not permitted issue

Tags: echo, beagleboneblack

Hello i am trying to use the echo command to load firmware to the PRU on the Beaglebone black with the following command:

```
root@beaglebone:~# echo 'am335x-pru1-fw' > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc2/firmware
```

However, i get the following error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

I can load firmware into pru0 without error but pru1 does not work. I am currently following the tutorial at this link if you are interested(download the zip file):
https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/967535/faq-where-did-the-rpmsg-quick-start-guide-wiki-go

Also the pru1 core seems to be running:

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc2# cat state

running
```

And when i try to stop it i get the same error message:

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc2# echo 'stop' > state
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

also my kernel on my bbb is:
4.19.94-ti-r42

The output of `ls -l` in the /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc2/ is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul 28 19:24 device -> ../../../44d00000.wkup_m3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 19:24 firmware
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 19:24 name
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jul 28 19:24 power
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 19:47 state
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul 28 19:24 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/remoteproc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 19:24 uevent
```

If you require any other info let me know and thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this file is read-only? Check permission to write with `ls -l /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc2/firmware`

Comment: Note that the user is logged in as root. Ordinary permissions do not apply to the root user.  Also note that on Linux systems, `/sys` exposes kernel structures. It's not an ordinary filesystem.

Comment: I did chmod ugo+rwx firmware, however i still get the same error. i will ad the output of `ls -l` to the post